# Vlc.DotNet - Show logging console/turn on file logging

Tags: c#, wpf, vlc

I'm playing with the new Vlc.DotNet library for WPF. It's available through Nuget (Vlc.DotNet.Wpf), and the Git repository for it is here: https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet .

The older VideoLan DotNet library (hosted here: https://vlcdotnet.codeplex.com) had some extremely useful capabilities related to file logging, showing the debug logging console, etc:

```
// Ignore the VLC configuration file
VlcContext.StartupOptions.IgnoreConfig = true;

// Enable file based logging
VlcContext.StartupOptions.LogOptions.LogInFile = true;

// Shows the VLC log console (in addition to the applications window)
VlcContext.StartupOptions.LogOptions.ShowLoggerConsole = true;

// Set the log level for the VLC instance
VlcContext.StartupOptions.LogOptions.Verbosity = VlcLogVerbosities.Debug;
```

I can't find these capabilities in the new repo. The documentation is non-existent and the sample projects are too light to glean much from. Does anyone know if it's possible to achieve any kind of VLC logging using the new Vlc.DotNet library?

Answer (score 2):

I found the correct location for me was in file (as of today 27.04.2015) Vlc.DotNet.Core.VlcMediaPlayer.VlcMediaPlayer.cs:

```
#if DEBUG
            Manager.CreateNewInstance(new[]
            {
                "--extraintf=logger",
                "--verbose=2"
            });
#else
            Manager.CreateNewInstance(null);
#endif
```

When you compile Vlc.DotNet in Release mode, you won't get the verbose logging any more.

Comment: In response to @Remy who wanted to edit this post a few hours ago (I cannot review suggestions, I lack points). The above code is the exact replica of author's code https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet/blob/master/src/Vlc.DotNet.Core/VlcMediaPlayer/VlcMediaPlayer.cs and is not my code.

Answer (score 0):

As at the time of writing these capabilities are hidden in the VlcManager class in the Vlc.DotNet.Core.Interops namespace. A string array of VLC startup options is passed to this class during instantiation:

```
Manager.CreateNewInstance(new[]
    {
        "--extraintf=logger",
        "--verbose=2"
    });
```

The only way to manually alter these options is to change them in the Vlc.DotNet source code, rebuild, and update any references to the newly built .dll .